# how to implement server side datatables using node-js , mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, datatables, server-side

I need to implement serverside datatables using node-js and mysql.
Currently I have implemented CLient -side datatables which is taking a lot of time to load more that 20,000 rows of data.

```
$('#progJobsTable').dataTable({
        processing: true,
        destroy:true,
        autoWidth:false,
         sAjaxDataProp: 'data',
        ajax:{
                url: "/sqlprogress",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {"id":id,"product":prdMain},
                dataSrc: ""
            },    
            columns: [ 
                { data : "job_name" },
                { data : "product"  },
                { data : "test_plan"  }

           ] ,"fnRowCallback":function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ){

                var dat1 = '<div >'+aData['job_name']+'</div>';
                var dat2 = '<div >'+aData['product']+'</div>';
                var dat3 = '<div >'+aData['test_plan']+'</div>';
                $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(dat1);
                $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html(dat2);
                $('td:eq(2)', nRow).html(dat3);
        }
    });
```

Now this code is working fine for results less that 6k -8k, but it is taking more than  8 - 9seconds to load 20,000 rows of data.

Comment: Tried using what code? You can't be vague like this and expect people to automatically know what you're talking about. What is a "long time"?

Comment: you could implement pagination for such volume of record. isn't?